# Sending Php-array to JavaScript-variable. Get a SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to send an array from php into a variable in my Javascript, but I get an `Unexpected token :-error`.

**My line in JavaScript, enclosed in script-tag in the php-document:**

```
arrayProductTypesFromDB = <?php echo json_encode(getProductTypes()); ?>;
```

**My code for the php function called upon above:**

```
function getProductTypes(){
        //here I have code which fetches from database and makes $result into an stdClass-object. This works fine, as I can successfully use that object within php
        foreach ($result as $r) {
            echo 'id: ' . $r->id . ", type: " . $r->type_name . ", ins: " . $r->nbr_ins . "<br>"; //this works fine
        }

        $array = json_decode(json_encode($result), true); //this turns it into an array, and this works fine within php
        echo $array[0]['id']; //no problem here
        return $array; //this is what I send to JavaScript.. and it doesn't work.
    }
```

Comment: You are doing `echo` here  echo $array[0]['id']; and then also doing `json_encode(getProductTypes())` it means it is outputting two times. Hence unexpected token error

Comment: @Murtaza Khursheed Hussain removing the "echo" produces the exact same error. I tried :/ EDIT: NO WAIT!!! I works now. Thank you! This solved it

Comment: @Murtaza Khursheed Hussain your first comment actually solved it. Thank you! It's working now

Comment: I am posting it as answer, accept it so other can be benefited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing echo here

```
echo $array[0]['id'];
```

and then also doing

```
json_encode(getProductTypes())
```

it means it is outputting two times. Hence unexpected token error. Calling the `getProductTypes()` function will output to strings.

Answer (score 0):

This error was within the php-function. As Murtaza Khursheed Hussain explained, my use of echo within the function before the return-statement caused issues. Removed that.. and now it is working!